# Best way to convert a small unit input to higher units, based on the input value

Tags: c

How to convert byte input to other bigger units in c?

I have large value in bytes, which I would like to convert to human readable units.

For example if i have `1212912891289218913891389318931893189138893189` bytes I want to display in a higher unit `Mb`/ `MB`, `Gb`/ `GB` to make it more readable.

OTOH, if I have `2 bytes`, I want to display it in this unit only.

How can I Achieve this?

Comment: `1212912891289218913891389318931893189138893189 byte to mb..` why not `Gb` or `GB`?

Comment: there's no unit called gb or mb you know

Answer (score 2):

Here'a a logical hint to do what you need.

1. Take the input in smallest unit [maybe bit/ Byte]
2. decide the next unit and the divisor to divide the input.
3. Store the result. Compare the result with the next divisor for next higher unit.

--> if the result is less than the next divisor, stop and print the output.

--> if the result is bigger, continue to step 3.

Write the code yourself. We'll be here to help if you face any issues.